# ClassNotFoundException when accessing a resource

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am getting this error when accessing a resource from a @Controller with my Spring MVC application:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openymsg.network.event.SessionListener
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    com.myapp.common.controller.MyController.getMessage(MyController.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

The application have two @Controllers, one which works and the other one when accessed throws ClassNotFoundException (above)

The application runs on Tomcat 6

I have the maven dependency placed in the pom for the library 'openymsg' and I can see from the 'Libraries->Maven Dependencies' there's the actual jar. I wonder why I get this error. Is it because  of a missing jar? Or something else, perhaps the library can't run on Tomcat or work with Spring?

Comment: Do I need to manually copy the jar needed to the tomcat lib folder? I didn't do this with Spring jars in the pom.

Comment: Looks like a scope problem. Check the scope of the jars containing `org.openymsg.network.event.SessionListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the Class is not accessible. Possible reasons are,

1. Missing Jar files
2. Wrong Path settings
3. You have done any Jar file upgradeand the new version has different class structure